# use columns as rows within a table

Tags: html, css

I have a row and within 4 columns, how could I make the last 2 columns go down and use all the available width

[image]

```
    <table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <th>example</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 8%;">
                    tittle1
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100%;">
                    colum1
                </td>
                <td style="width: 8%;">
                    tittle2
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100%;">
                    colum2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please share your code that you've already worked with

Comment: I have my table like this, but I must make the last 2 columns go down and occupy the entire width without using another row

Comment: use `<td colspan="3">`

Comment: I already tried but the last 2 columns were not scrolled

Comment: would you more clear about your expected result ....

Comment: I would like the first 2 columns to occupy 100%, and the last 2 (title2 and column2) to go down and be located below the first 2 but without using another row

Comment: i think table will not give you expected result... i think you need to try other way..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tables for this behaviour, you can use flexbox where you can wrap things on a new line if the content doesn't fit the space left, or you should use divs with floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS property `colspan` or `rowspan`.

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <th>example</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 8%;">
                    tittle1
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100%;">
                    colum1
                </td>
                <td style="width: 8%; colspan:3: rowspan:3">  #here are the changes
                    tittle2
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100%; colspan:3 ; rowspan:3"> #here are the changes
                    colum2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox.

```css
.parents {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
    flex: 50%;
}
.parents2 .child:nth-of-type(1n+3) {
    background: red;
    flex: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parents">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="parents parents2">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <th>example</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                tittle1
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                colum1
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                tittle2
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                colum2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

notes: *here is edited styles to width 50%*

---

**OR try this also**

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <th>example</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    tittle1
                </td>
                <td >
                    colum1
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td >
                    tittle2
                </td>
                <td >
                    colum2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

notes: *here is added A table row again `<tr>`*

***I hope this will help you to get it !***